# Variadic Macro for custom print function with argument expansion in C

Tags: c

I am trying replicate the printf for my application. Instead of using stdout, I have a different set of user specific pointers that basically point to the location one wants to print something. So instead of having:

```
#define print(fmt, ...) printf(stdout, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```

I want something like this:

```
#define print(x, fmt, ...) dev_printf(x->pointer_to_a_screen, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Here the expectation is that the x is a struct that stores a users current context and information with it. I want to automatically expand x to use the pointer_to_a_screen which basically tells dev_printf where to print the given input. Expectation is the dev_printf needs to behave as any other standard printf function and the user can specify variable arguments.

Is this even possible? I keep getting a compile error for above #define print repeatedly and I cant understand why? I can't expand the first argument?

Comment: If you're getting an error, please, please *include the exact error text in your question*. You can still edit to put that in there.

Comment: [fprintf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm) sounds similar to this.

Comment: @tadman The error turned out a mistake at my end. I realized later it was quite silly. I will make sure to include it in my next post. Thanks to point it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trailing comma has to be removed in case no arguments are passed. Ie.

```
#define print(x, fmt, ...) dev_printf(x->pointer_to_a_screen, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
print(something, "arg: %d", i); 
// expands to dev_printf(something->pointer_to_a_screen, "arg: %d", i); 
// all fine
// but:
print(something, "no arg"); 
// expands to dev_printf(something->pointer_to_a_screen, "not arg", ); 
//                                                                ^^
```

In  your case you can just:

```
#define print(x, ...) dev_printf(x->pointer_to_a_screen, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Newer code should use `__VA_OPT__`:

```
#define print(x, fmt, ...) dev_printf(x->pointer_to_a_screen, fmt __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

In days before `__VA_OPT__` it was typical to use [GNU extension `##__VA_ARGS__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros)to:

```
#define print(x, fmt, ...) dev_printf(x->pointer_to_a_screen, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

You can also use POSIX [`fopencookie`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html) to create a custom stream that you could manipulate with normal `fprintf` functions.

Each of standard `*printf` function have equivalent `v*printf` function. The best is to provide your own `dev_vprintf` function that would take a `va_list` and then provide a simple wrapper:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
// ex. on gcc compiler this causes printf-like warnings to happen
__attribute__((__format__(__printf__, 2, 3)))
#endif
return_type print(some_type *x, const char *fmt, ...) {
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, fmt);
   return_type e = dev_vprintf(x->pointer_to_a_screen, fmt, va);
   va_end(va);
   return e;
}
```

Such wrapper will check for type mismatches, is easy to maintain and it's easy to check for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't quite understand clearly the trailing comma error. Thanks for the other suggestions too. I think I wanted something similar to fopencookie() but I think using fopencookie would be a better choice as a overall solution. It seems that I have kind of over complicated my implementation...

Thanks again for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would not use macro for that

```
int mystrangeprintf(MYTYPE *x, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int length;
    char buff[256];
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    length = vsnprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
    dev_printString(x->pointer_to_a_screen, buff);
    return length;
}
```